# The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version: project ':flutter_launch' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, flutter

[image]android studio generate ERROR: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher. but it already have Kotlin version 1.3.50 what should i do any one help